# Liferay Web Content Not Displaying

Tags: liferay

I am simply adding Web Content to my portal and trying to display some simple text, Easy Stuff!

However, I've noticed that if I make the web content large (i.e., 80 lines of text instead of 40), it displays nothing!

I can't figure out the reason for this, has anyone else ever had this issue?

Cheers!

-Running Liferay 6.1.1 GA2 on WebLogic Server 12c

Comment: sorry, I've never seen it. Do you see anything in the logs? Does the Web Content Display portlet display? Or are you displaying in a different portlet? Sure you've published, not just "saved as draft" or "submitted for publication"? As I've never seen it, I'm even asking the more stupid sounding questions in the hope to point something obvious that you might have missed...

Comment: No sir, I've been doing everything by the book here. Nothing in the logs. It's really dependent on the length of the web content which is very odd. I'm thinking maybe there's a threshold on these portlets. Very odd. Much disappoint.

Comment: I don't have Weblogic here to test, but I have just tested to paste http://baconipsum.com/?paras=50&type=all-meat&start-with-lorem=1 to Webcontent, 5 times, works perfectly. What database are you using? Maybe there's a problem storing that text in the DB? I remember odd problems with Oracle's thin driver with 2000 characters, but assumed that was ancient history. Can you find the character limit, maybe account for UTF-8 multibyte.

Comment: I'll try to find this, and I love you for showing me baconipsum I am immediately starving!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I redefined in portal-ext.properties the following property:

com.liferay.portal.upload.LiferayFileItem.threshold.size=262144

You can control the limitation of content size by increasing this value to a higher number. The value is in bytes.